# Qt5 forward signals

Tags: qt, qt5

Using the old syntax, it was possible to forward a signal eg:

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(valueChanged(QString,QString)), this, SIGNAL(updateValue(QString,QString)));
```

I like using the [new Qt5 syntax](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). Is it possible to use the new syntax to forward a signal?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Signal is nothing more than just a plain method. So you can use it as is. Something like this:

```
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, receiver, &Receiver::updateValue);
```